# How does Parallel.Invoke() method works?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, plinq

Does `Parallel.Invoke()` methods uses multiple threads to execute each action in a different thread.

Example:

```
Parallel.Invoke(() =>
    {
        YourFirstAction(param1, param2, param3, param4);
    },  // close first Action
    () =>
    {
        YourSecondAction(param1, param2, param3, param4);
    }//close second Action
); //close parallel.invoke
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460705(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can simply look for yourself http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,8cd0672978c64e86